# How to get the stack details based on resource name in AWS Cloud-formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, boto3

Is there any way I can find the stack name from the resource created?
Let's say I have cft template which creates a stack A and Resource B.
Then due to requirement, I have to create another stack C for the same resource B.

But the creae of stack C doesn't allow me to create Resource B, because Stack A already locked with it.
So, my purpose is to find the earlier stack which owns for the resource B and delete the stack A.
Then, Implement Stack B with CFT and then create the resource B.

I'm trying to use boto3.

Answer (score 2):

> In addition to any tags you define, AWS CloudFormation automatically
> creates the following stack-level tags with the prefix aws::
>
> aws:cloudformation:logical-id
>
> aws:cloudformation:stack-id
>
> aws:cloudformation:stack-name
>
> The aws: prefix is reserved for AWS use

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html